# Laravel run package migration by composer update automatic

Tags: laravel-5

I have a package and my ServiceProvider copies the migrations. This works fine after php artisan migrate. But now i want to execute the package migration when i do composer update name/name-package.
So, php artisan update name/packagename and directly automaticly migrate.

How can i achieve that?

```
$this->publishes([
    __DIR__ . '/database/migrations' => $this->app->databasePath() . '/migrations'
], 'migrations');
```

Comment: do you need to run migration after any package update, or a specific package update?

Comment: @AlexG. direct after composer update. So somewhere in the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in application (not package) composer.json

```
"scripts": {
"post-update-cmd": [
    "php artisan optimize",
    "php artisan migrate"
    ]
}
```

the order of commands is up to you. Also, you may create a command or use `php artisan vendor:publish --provider=...` to move the migrations

Comment: Is this in the app composer.json or package?